# Correr script en Rstudio en Windows

Tags: r, windows, script, rstudio

Tengo un script que abre una archivo csv, lo limpia y genera diversos archivos csv diferentes. Me gustaría poder lanzarlo de forma automática, sin necesidad de cambiar el archivo csv que aparece en el script cada vez que lo aplico en uno nuevo csv.

Me han dicho que añada las siguientes líneas al principio de mi script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
tabla <- read.csv(args[[1]])
```

Pero esto es para linux y no me funciona.

Cuando pongo en Rstudio:

```
Rscript miscript.R mitabla.csv
```

me devuelve error y me dice que hay un elemento inesperado en Rscript

¿Alguien me puede indicar cómo corregirlo?

Editado 23/07/2023

A petición de Patricio Moracho, incluyo el script completo más abajo. El error que me devuelve Rstudio es el siguiente:

```
Rscript metabolomica_v4.R genus_V3V4.csv
Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript metabolomica_v4.R"
```

El script completo es:

```
# carga de argumentos
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

# limpieza csv lecturas
meta <- read_csv(args[[1]]) # lee el archivo csv donde están las lecturas
meta <- meta %>% separate(...1, paste0("taxon", 1:6), sep = ';') # separa la primera columna en 6, una por taxón, a partir del caracter ";"
colnames(meta)[1] <- "dominio" # nombra la columna 1 como "dominio"
colnames(meta)[2] <- "phyllum" # nombra la columna 1 como "phyllum"
colnames(meta)[3] <- "clase" # nombra la columna 1 como "clase"
colnames(meta)[4] <- "orden" # nombra la columna 1 como "orden"
colnames(meta)[5] <- "familia" # nombra la columna 1 como "familia"
colnames(meta)[6] <- "genero" # nombra la columna 1 como "genero"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'd__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "d__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'p__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "p__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'c__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "c__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'o__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "o__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'f__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "f__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, 'g__','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres "g__"
meta <- meta %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, ' ','') # elimina de cada valor los caracteres " "
meta[meta == "__"] <- NA # cambia los valores "__" por NA (valores perdidos)
meta[meta == "uncultured"] <- NA # cambia los valores "uncultured" por NA (valores perdidos)
meta$genero <- ifelse(meta$genero == meta$familia, NA, meta$genero) # compara genero con familia, si son iguales, introduce un NA (valor perdido) en genero, si no son iguales, deja el valor que había
meta$familia <- ifelse(meta$familia == meta$orden, NA, meta$familia) # compara familia con orden, si son iguales, introduce un NA (valor perdido) en familia, si no son iguales, deja el valor que había
meta$orden <- ifelse(meta$orden == meta$clase, NA, meta$orden) # compara orden con clase, si son iguales, introduce un NA (valor perdido) en orden, si no son iguales, deja el valor que había
meta$clase <- ifelse(meta$clase == meta$phyllum, NA, meta$clase) # compara calse con phyllum, si son iguales, introduce un NA (valor perdido) en clase, si no son iguales, deja el valor que había
meta$phyllum <- ifelse(meta$phyllum == meta$dominio, NA, meta$phyllum) # compara phyllum con dominio, si son iguales, introduce un NA (valor perdido) en phyllum, si no son iguales, deja el valor que había
meta <- meta[!(meta$dominio == 'Eukaryota'),] # elimina todas las filas completas donde en dominio hay "Eukaryota"
write.csv2(meta,"lecturas.csv") #exporta la tabla "meta" a un archivo csv (lecturas)

# creación csv dominio
domlec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("domlec")
domlec <- domlec[ , -2:-6] # elimina las columnas de la 2 a la 6
nc <- ncol(domlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
domlec <- domlec %>% group_by(dominio) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico dominio, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
domlec <- domlec[!is.na(domlec$dominio),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
domlec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(domlec), t(domlec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(domlec) <- domlec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
domlec <- domlec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(domlec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(domlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
domlec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(domlec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
domdic <- domlec # copia la tabla "domlec" en la tabla "domdic"
dompor <- domlec # copia la tabla "domlec" en la tabla "dompor"
domcer <- domlec # copia la tabla "domlec" en la tabla "domcer"
colnames(domlec)[2:nc] <- paste("domlec_", colnames(domlec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "domlec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(domlec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(domlec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(domlec, "domlec.csv") # exporta la tabla "domlec" a un csv llamado domlec
domdic[2:nc] <- ifelse(domdic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(domdic)[2:nc] <- paste("domdic_", colnames(domdic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "domdic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(domdic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(domdic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(domdic, "domdic.csv") # exporta la tabla "domdic" a un csv llamado domdic
dompor$suma = rowSums(dompor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
dompor <- dompor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "dompor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "dompor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
dompor <- dompor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(dompor, "dompor.csv") # exporta la tabla "dompor" a un csv llamado dompor
domcer[domcer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(domcer, "domcer.csv") # exporta la tabla "domcer" a un csv llamado domcer

# creación csv phyllum
phylec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("phylec")
phylec <- phylec[ , -3:-6] # elimina las columnas de la 3 a la 6
phylec <- phylec[ , -1] # elimina la columna 1
nc <- ncol(phylec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
phylec <- phylec %>% group_by(phyllum) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico phyllum, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
phylec <- phylec[!is.na(phylec$phyllum),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
phylec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(phylec), t(phylec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(phylec) <- phylec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
phylec <- phylec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(phylec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(phylec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
phylec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(phylec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
phydic <- phylec # copia la tabla "phylec" en la tabla "phydic"
phypor <- phylec # copia la tabla "phylec" en la tabla "phypor"
phycer <- phylec # copia la tabla "phylec" en la tabla "phycer"
colnames(phylec)[2:nc] <- paste("phylec_", colnames(phylec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "phylec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(phylec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(phylec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(phylec, "phylec.csv") # exporta la tabla "phylec" a un csv llamado phylec
phydic[2:nc] <- ifelse(phydic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(phydic)[2:nc] <- paste("phydic_", colnames(phydic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "phydic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(phydic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(phydic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(phydic, "phydic.csv") # exporta la tabla "phydic" a un csv llamado phydic
phypor$suma = rowSums(phypor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
phypor <- phypor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "phypor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "phypor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
phypor <- phypor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(phypor, "phypor.csv") # exporta la tabla "phypor" a un csv llamado phypor
phycer[phycer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(phycer, "phycer.csv") # exporta la tabla "phycer" a un csv llamado phycer

# creación csv clase
clalec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("clalec")
clalec <- clalec[ , -4:-6] # elimina las columnas de la 4 a la 6
clalec <- clalec[ , -1:-2] # elimina las columnas de la 1 a la 2
nc <- ncol(clalec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
clalec <- clalec %>% group_by(clase) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico clase, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
clalec <- clalec[!is.na(clalec$clase),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
clalec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(clalec), t(clalec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(clalec) <- clalec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
clalec <- clalec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(clalec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(clalec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
clalec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(clalec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
cladic <- clalec # copia la tabla "clalec" en la tabla "cladic"
clapor <- clalec # copia la tabla "clalec" en la tabla "clapor"
clacer <- clalec # copia la tabla "clalec" en la tabla "clacer"
colnames(clalec)[2:nc] <- paste("clalec_", colnames(clalec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "clalec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(clalec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(clalec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(clalec, "clalec.csv") # exporta la tabla "clalec" a un csv llamado clalec
cladic[2:nc] <- ifelse(cladic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(cladic)[2:nc] <- paste("cladic_", colnames(cladic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "cladic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(cladic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(cladic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(cladic, "cladic.csv") # exporta la tabla "cladic" a un csv llamado cladic
clapor$suma = rowSums(clapor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
clapor <- clapor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "clapor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "clapor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
clapor <- clapor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(clapor, "clapor.csv") # exporta la tabla "clapor" a un csv llamado clapor
clacer[clacer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(clacer, "clacer.csv") # exporta la tabla "clacer" a un csv llamado clacer

# creación csv orden
ordlec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("ordlec")
ordlec <- ordlec[ , -5:-6] # elimina las columnas de la 5 a la 6
ordlec <- ordlec[ , -1:-3] # elimina las columnas de la 1 a la 3
nc <- ncol(ordlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
ordlec <- ordlec %>% group_by(orden) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico orden, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
ordlec <- ordlec[!is.na(ordlec$orden),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
ordlec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(ordlec), t(ordlec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(ordlec) <- ordlec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
ordlec <- ordlec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(ordlec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(ordlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
ordlec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(ordlec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
orddic <- ordlec # copia la tabla "ordlec" en la tabla "orddic"
ordpor <- ordlec # copia la tabla "ordlec" en la tabla "ordpor"
ordcer <- ordlec # copia la tabla "ordlec" en la tabla "ordcer"
colnames(ordlec)[2:nc] <- paste("ordlec_", colnames(ordlec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "ordlec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(ordlec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(ordlec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(ordlec, "ordlec.csv") # exporta la tabla "ordlec" a un csv llamado ordlec
orddic[2:nc] <- ifelse(orddic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(orddic)[2:nc] <- paste("orddic_", colnames(orddic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "orddic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(orddic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(orddic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(orddic, "orddic.csv") # exporta la tabla "orddic" a un csv llamado orddic
ordpor$suma = rowSums(ordpor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
ordpor <- ordpor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "ordpor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "ordpor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
ordpor <- ordpor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(ordpor, "ordpor.csv") # exporta la tabla "ordpor" a un csv llamado ordpor
ordcer[ordcer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(ordcer, "ordcer.csv") # exporta la tabla "ordcer" a un csv llamado ordcer

# creación csv familia
famlec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("famlec")
famlec <- famlec[ , -6] # elimina la columna 6
famlec <- famlec[ , -1:-4] # elimina las columnas de la 1 a la 4
nc <- ncol(famlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
famlec <- famlec %>% group_by(familia) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico familia, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
famlec <- famlec[!is.na(famlec$familia),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
famlec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(famlec), t(famlec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(famlec) <- famlec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
famlec <- famlec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(famlec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(famlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
famlec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(famlec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
famdic <- famlec # copia la tabla "famlec" en la tabla "famdic"
fampor <- famlec # copia la tabla "famlec" en la tabla "fampor"
famcer <- famlec # copia la tabla "famlec" en la tabla "famcer"
colnames(famlec)[2:nc] <- paste("famlec_", colnames(famlec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "famlec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(famlec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(famlec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(famlec, "famlec.csv") # exporta la tabla "famlec" a un csv llamado famlec
famdic[2:nc] <- ifelse(famdic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(famdic)[2:nc] <- paste("famdic_", colnames(famdic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "famdic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(famdic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(famdic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(famdic, "famdic.csv") # exporta la tabla "famdic" a un csv llamado famdic
fampor$suma = rowSums(fampor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
fampor <- fampor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "fampor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "fampor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
fampor <- fampor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(fampor, "fampor.csv") # exporta la tabla "fampor" a un csv llamado fampor
famcer[famcer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(famcer, "famcer.csv") # exporta la tabla "famcer" a un csv llamado famcer

# creación csv género
genlec <- meta # copia la tabla "meta" en una nueva tabla ("genlec")
genlec <- genlec[ , -1:-5] # elimina las columnas de la 1 a la 5
nc <- ncol(genlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
genlec <- genlec %>% group_by(genero) %>% summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2:nc], .funs = sum) # agrupa todos los resultados de idéntico genero, y devuelve la suma de las lecturas de la columna 2 hasta la última columna
genlec <- genlec[!is.na(genlec$genero),] # borra la última fila si en la 1a celda hay un NA (es un conteo de los valores NA (valores perdidos))
genlec <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(genlec), t(genlec))) # traspone la tabla, intercambiando las filas por las columnas
colnames(genlec) <- genlec[1, ] # asigna como nombre a cada columna el valor que hay en la primera fila
genlec <- genlec[-1, ] # borra la primera fila
colnames(genlec)[1] <- "paciente" # asigna a la primera columna el nombre de "paciente"
nc <- ncol(genlec) # extrae el número de columnas de la tabla
genlec[, 2:nc] <- as.data.frame(apply(genlec[, 2:nc], 2, as.numeric)) # formatea las columnas de la 2 a la última como numéricas
gendic <- genlec # copia la tabla "genlec" en la tabla "gendic"
genpor <- genlec # copia la tabla "genlec" en la tabla "genpor"
gencer <- genlec # copia la tabla "genlec" en la tabla "gencer"
colnames(genlec)[2:nc] <- paste("genlec_", colnames(genlec)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "genlec_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(genlec)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(genlec) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(genlec, "genlec.csv") # exporta la tabla "genlec" a un csv llamado genlec
gendic[2:nc] <- ifelse(gendic[2:nc] == 0, 2, 1) # asigna a cada valor de la tabla un "no" (2) si es 0 y un "sí" (1) si no es 0 (>0)
colnames(gendic)[2:nc] <- paste("gendic_", colnames(gendic)[2:nc]) # pega en el nombre de cada columna, de la 2 a la última el prefijo "gendic_"
vec <- gsub(" ", "", colnames(gendic)) # genera un vector con los nombres de las columnas y elimina los espacios
colnames(gendic) <- vec # pega como nombres de las variables los nombres que hay en el vector
write_csv2(gendic, "gendic.csv") # exporta la tabla "gendic" a un csv llamado gendic
genpor$suma = rowSums(genpor[ , 2:nc]) # añade una nueva columna que es la suma de la columna 2 a la última columna
genpor <- genpor %>% mutate(across(c(2:nc), ~.x/suma, .names = "genpor_{.col}")) # para cada columna, de la 2 a la última (sin contar la columna "suma") calcula una nueva columna que es el valor asignado dividido por la suma correspondiente (normalización a 1), y pone como nombre de las nuevas columnas el mismo nombre con el prefijo "genpor_"
nc <- nc + 1 # suma 1 al número de columnas
genpor <- genpor[ , -2:-nc] # borra desde la columna 2 a la columna "suma"
write_csv2(genpor, "genpor.csv") # exporta la tabla "genpor" a un csv llamado genpor
gencer[gencer == "0"] <- NA # cambia todos los 0 por NA (valores perdidos)
write_csv2(gencer, "gencer.csv") # exporta la tabla "gencer" a un csv llamado gencer
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Al menos el código que muestras es totalmente funcional en Windows, por lo que el problema debería estar en oro lugar, agrega el error exacto y el script completo que estás ejecutando.

Comment: Hola, @PatricioMoracho
He hecho lo que me comentas.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado. Era un problema menor por ser nuevo en esto. Disculpad mi torpeza.

Estaba insertando la instrucción de Rscript en la consola en vez de en el terminal. Al hacerlo en este último, funciona bien.

Saludos.

Comment: En ese caso, marca tu pregunta como resuelta por favor

Comment: Yo eliminaría directamente tanto la pregunta como la respuesta, no aporta nada ni lo uno ni lo otro.